# Entity Framework Core insert parent entity and update its nested child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Here's my situation, I need to implement a sync system where data are created in client, and they are sent in JSON format to server then saved to a temporary place(NoSql). There is another process(written in c# dotnet core) which read the temporary records and insert them into MSSQL.

Let me show a simplified version of my entities

```
class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}

class Worker
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to insert a Worker entity into MSSQL, I do not know if my Company entity has already synced.
Two possible situations:

- Company exists. Insert this Worker object causes a Duplicate key exception
- Company does not exist. Insert can be done but the subsequent insert operation becomes first situation.

How can I solve this if I do not manually extract out the Company entity and check its existence before insertion.

My goal is

- to insert a worker with a company foreign key, if the foreign key exists, update(or ignore) it.
- achieve this without manually handle the foreign key since there are dozens of entities, doing so will make the code unmanageable...

Hope I've provided information needed, if not do let me know and I will update my question. Thanks!

Comment: `manually extract out the Company entity and check its existence before insertion` I would suggest that is the best thing to do.

Comment: @mjwills ok..seems like i have to consider this...